# How to implement 2D conv with already flattened input data

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to train a CNN model with TensorFlow on a dataset with images of shape 28x28, already flattened as vectors of length 784.

I want to use Conv2D layers in Tensorflow but as my input is already flattened, I don't know what is the best way to do this.

Is there a kind of layer that performs the opposite of flatten ? Should I write a custom model with subclassing API and numpy's reshape ? Or is it possible to perform 2D convolution with a 1D array ?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: [`Reshape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape) layer? You should never use NumPy's reshape with TensorFlow tensors, if anything use [`tf.reshape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to do that, but here is the approach that might be helpful. Working with TensorFlow 2 and Keras:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3),padding='same',input_shape=([28,28,3])))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Reshape([28,28,8]))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(3,(3,3),padding='same',input_shape=([28,28,3])))
```

The only downside is that you should exactly know the dimension which you what to reshape here.

If you need more information you have to provide more in your question. This is as far as I could write with the limited amount of information you provided.

Comment: I don't know if I was clear. My input data is of shape (None*784), but in fact the 784 stands for 28*28 pictures. As my data is made of pictures, I want to use a CNN architecture. But in general, the input has shape (None, 28, 28, 1) or (None, 28, 28, 3). I want to threat the input as if it was a picture of shape 28*28, but it is in real life a 784-length vector.

Comment: @Nathane Does my approach help?. It would be nice to include the things you put in the comment to your question. It will help the readability. Also, a piece of code will help. So we better know your efforts. Also, Include the version of TF which you are using. The more info you give, the better solution you will receive.